# How to implement horizontall scalability using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, nginx, scalability

So, I've web application which structure is based on this file structure: https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application .
My app also has a connection to mongoDB on Mlab.

what my app does:

- allows users to login/signup;
- retrieves data from mlab;
- retrieved data can be rated by users;
- retrieved data can be deleted by admin;
- users can add data to db (data is training plans);

Now I need to make my app horizontally scalable, but I am a bit lost here:

•Sine I assume there i no real-time activities I shoudn't need something like socket.io?
•Should I add some sort of MQ (rabbitMQ, ZMQ, etc.): If so, perhaps any pointers on how to, because most of the examples just use simple text messages.

•I am quite sure I would need some load balancer. Nginx, HaProxy... I probably should change my express server setup to listen to multiple ports first, is that right?

Or am I completely wrong about this?

P.S.: Hope this isn't too broad question.

Comment: I hate to say it, but the question is incredibly broad.

Answer (score 1):

Different needs require different approaches :)

These can vary according to your needs. Not every scalable application has to have them.If you want the application to be asynchronous, you can take all the requests in a queue and return to the client instantly.You may then need a push mechanism to notify the client that the operation is over. (Socket.io, RabbitMQ etc)

Of course you will need a reverse proxy to distribute requests to different servers load balanced or workload basis (HAProxy etc.)

The first thing you need to pay attention to when you want to scale the application is to have a stateless structure.Or get them out of the process.(For example session, cache, file server)The second thing you need to be aware of is the authentication phase.A client that logged in from ServerA may encounter "unauthorized" on ServerB on subsequent requests.You should also think about the resources used by the application.While these resources serve a single server, they will begin to respond to millions of requests from five to ten servers simultaneously.There are things like monitoring instances.And a lot of things like that.

These are the things you should really think about :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. For now I've simply added nginx to listen to localhost i.e port 80 and also added upstream servers, like 81,82,83 etc...It does seem that the more servers I add the faster program runs. with ab test runing 20k requests and 1k concurrency the result while  running 3 servers was ~35s where as running the same test on single server result ~120s.  Can I assume this is horizontal scalability working or this is something else?